# Access system32 from VisualStudio 2019 build script

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file

In a post build step i want check if OpenSSH.Client and OpenSSH.Server is installed and install it if it is not there. Checking the installed features with Powershell needs administrative privileges.
Therefore i test the existence of the relevant OpenSSH commands with the following code (extract of long script)

```
SET /a res=0
SET /a three=3
%windir%\system32\OpenSSH\ssh-keygen.exe /?
echo Errorlevel %ERRORLEVEL%
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==%three% (SET /a res=%res%+1)
%windir%\system32\OpenSSH\ssh-keyscan.exe /?
echo Errorlevel %ERRORLEVEL%
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==%three% (SET /a res=%res%+1)
SET /a check=0
IF %res% == %check% (
  echo already installed
  goto skipopenSSH
)
echo installation
:skipopenSSH
```

By checking the existence of the commands no admin privileges are necessary for the check so a normal build will not cause a administrative popup.
On cmd.exe it works fine, but as a post build step in Visual Studio both commands in %windir%\systrem32\OpenSSH are not found, although the variable is expanded to the same c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\*.exe as if executed on commandline.
After trying the different find mechanisms which all fail i made a test batch file `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-keyscan.exe /?`
which leads to a file not found error if executed as a post build step. So the real question should be: Modifies the visual studio build step commandline the path?

Comment: I would have done `where ssh-keygen.exe | findstr /i "ssh"` then use `errorlevel` of `findstr` to do the rest.

Comment: That was my first try, but it results always in file not found when executed as build script. Therefore i hard coded the path but it fails also.

Comment: so this would result in file not found? `where ssh-keygen.exe | findstr /i "ssh" && echo found`

Comment: I´ve a german windows i think the english text is pattern not found. Errorlevel is 1
```findstr``` cannot find ssh because the file is not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory `OpenSSH` exists in directory `%SystemRoot%\System32` with the files `ssh-keygen.exe` and `ssh-keyscan.exe` depending on version of Windows 10. The directory `%SystemRoot%\System32` is for 64-bit applications on 64-bit Windows. But Visual Studio is a 32-bit application and for that reason 32-bit Windows command processor in directory `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` is executed to process the batch file with the commands to execute as post build step.

Microsoft documented with [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/wow64-implementation-details), [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) and [Registry Keys Affected by WOW64](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys) and other documentation pages how Windows on Windows 64 works.

All file system accesses to `%windir%\system32\OpenSSH` in the batch file processed by 32-bit `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` being started by 32-bit Visual Studio results in the approach to access `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\OpenSSH` which does not exist at all. There is no subdirectory `OpenSSH` in Windows system directory for 32-bit applications.

One solution would be using the following code for the batch file executed as post build step.

```
rem This simple check is for 32-bit Windows and for 64-bit Windows with batch
rem file executed in 64-bit environment by 64-bit Windows command processor.
set FolderSSH=%SystemRoot%\System32\OpenSSH
if exist %FolderSSH%\ssh-keygen.exe if exist %FolderSSH%\ssh-keyscan.exe goto UseOpenSSH

rem This check is for 64-bit Windows with batch file executed
rem in 32-bit environment by 32-bit Windows command processor.
if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\cmd.exe set FolderSSH=%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\OpenSSH
if exist %FolderSSH%\ssh-keygen.exe if exist %FolderSSH%\ssh-keyscan.exe goto UseOpenSSH

rem Search entire system drive on machines without Windows 10 or with older
rem versions of Windows 10 with OpenSSH not installed at all by default.
for /F "delims=" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\where.exe /R %SystemDrive%\ ssh-keygen.exe 2^>nul') do (
    if exist "%%~dpIssh-keyscan.exe" for %%J in ("%%~dpI.") do set "FolderSSH=%%~fJ" & goto UseOpenSSH
)
echo ERROR: ssh-keygen.exe AND ssh-keyscan.exe not found.
rem More code to handle this use case.
exit /B

:UseOpenSSH
echo Found ssh-keygen and ssh-keyscan in: "%FolderSSH%"
rem More code to handle this use case with existing SSH tools.
```

The remarks explain most of the code. The inner **FOR** loop is used to get the full qualified name of the directory containing `ssh-keygen.exe` **and** `ssh-keyscan.exe` without backslash at end of the folder path to have `FolderSSH` defined always without a backlash at end for further usage in the batch file.

Please note that it is safe to use `%FolderSSH%\ssh-keygen.exe` and `%FolderSSH%\ssh-keyscan.exe` without surrounding `"` at beginning of the batch script as it is impossible that `%FolderSSH%` expands to a folder path containing a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``.
But `"%FolderSSH%\ssh-keygen.exe"` and `"%FolderSSH%\ssh-keyscan.exe"` must be used on the command lines below the label `UseOpenSSH` because it could happen that **WHERE** was used to find the two executables anywhere on system drive and for that reason `%FolderSSH%` could expand now to a folder path containing a space or a character with a special meaning for Windows command processor outside a double quoted argument string.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `where /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `where` command line with using a separate command process started in background with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line between `'` appended as additional arguments on which `2^>nul` became already `2>nul`.

Answer (score 2):

The following idea also uses the `where.exe` command, as mentioned in the comments. This one will search the system drive for `ssh-keyscan.exe`, and if found will ensure that `ssh-keygen.exe` is also located there. If both are located in the same place, then it is considered as already installed:

```batch-file
@Set "dirOpenSSH="
@For /F Delims^= %%G In (
    '%__AppDir__%where.exe /R %SystemDrive%\ ssh-keyscan.exe 2^>NUL'
)Do @For /F Delims^= %%H In (
    '%__AppDir__%where.exe "%%~dpG.":ssh-keygen.exe 2^>NUL'
)Do @Set "dirOpenSSH=%%~dpH"
@If Defined dirOpenSSH (
    Echo OpenSSH is available at %dirOpenSSH%.
    %__AppDir__%timeout.exe 3 /NoBreak>NUL
    GoTo skipopenSSH
)
@Echo OpenSSH is not available, beginning installation.
@%__AppDir__%timeout.exe 3 >NUL

:skipopenSSH
```

*Please note that `where.exe` and `timeout.exe` require a minimum OS version of Windows NT 6.x*

**As your application is currently a 32-bit one, the console session it is using is not accessing the 64-bit locations. To fix that you could replace `%__AppDir__%where.exe`, with `%SystemRoot%\SysNative\where.exe`**

---

It is probably worth mentioning that in the versions of [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) with OpenSSH part of the base OS, the location, `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\`, should exist in `%PATH%`, so you should be able to find your files directly using them:

```batch-file
%__AppDir__%where.exe ssh-keygen.exe
```

```batch-file
%__AppDir__%where.exe ssh-keyscan.exe
```

```batch-file
For %I In (ssh-keygen.exe) Do @Echo %~$PATH:I
```

```batch-file
For %I In (ssh-keyscan.exe) Do @Echo %~$PATH:I
```

---

I have found on the systems which have upgraded from an earlier version of Windows, that many of the default locations using `C:\Windows` were replicated, but using `%SYSTEMROOT%`/`%SystemRoot%` instead.


In that state, the `Where` command and `For`'s `%~$PATH:` failed to locate some items which did exist and should have been found.

Removing the duplicated items, *I removed those which were carried over, (those not using variables)*, although removing either format seems to have worked fine.

Both `where` and `%~$PATH:` were then functioning as intended.

Comment: It works on commandline but as build script terminats with  ERROR: Input redirection is not supported. Process is terminated immediately. (This is translated from the german error message)
It seems as if the vs command line yields system32

Comment: I didn't provide a command line answer, @uenz. My answer is a complete [[tag:batch-file]] which requires absolutely no modification, additions or omissions before line `12`, which you can do what you like with! Additionally, there is no input redirection in my provided script and the only redirection used is unwanted output to the NUL device. Please do not, ask questions about changes you've made to my answer, my answer and code should be judged as written only. Questions regarding changes outside of that are new ones and outside of the scope of your initially posted question.

Comment: I have additionally posted an emboldened edit @uenz, based upon the information noted by Mofi, that you're trying to access 64-bit locations from a 32-bit process. Please note however, that you may not be able to use executables designed for 64-bit execution in your 32-bit environment, but finding out if it is installed shouldn't be an issue.